# Process.Start() cannot open File(.txt,.xls,.pdf,.dwg) in client machine in IIS7

Tags: c#, file-io, iis-7, web-deployment, process.start

```
Process.Start() will start a process on the machine where the method is called.  In the case of an ASP.NET application, this starts the process on the web server, rather than the client.  This works correctly in testing when your server and client are both the same machine.
```

Is there any way to open those files just like we open in windows so that user can edit it, n on CLT+S it can save to the respective directory in the SERVER.
NOTE: I have already mapped the server directory location to  network path. (J:)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You cannot open files on the client machine from a serverside web application, nor is this possible directly from the browser because of security reasons.

Options are:

- Letting the user download  a file from your server, have them edit it and then re-upload it with their changes.
- Creating a browser extension / plugin that does this, so the user doesn't have to manually open their editor and upload the file again.
- Create an editor like Google Docs / Office 365, so users can edit serverside documents in their browser.

Comment: @CodeCaster-
Creating a browser extension / plugin that does this, so the user doesn't have to manually open their editor and upload the file again.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't  it possible with network path mapping, as from there user can open it just like opening in its own local.

Comment: Creatign a browser extension to download documents, open the appropriate editor and upload them after they have been saved is reasonably trivial, but you'd have to determine which browsers you want to support and find out how you create or download plugins to do that.

Comment: As for your second comment - no, the mapping doesn't matter, the problem is starting the editor on the client. You _can_ try using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11339908/266143) using `GetObject("","Word.Application");` and pass the path to thefile on the server, but this'll only work in IE and you'll have to find a COM object for each editor you wish to start.