# file full path on the server - ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net, filepath

I have a word document file in a new folder named 'Document_Files'. I have Microsoft Package installed on the server, I am basically trying to open this file on server. It opens it when I run it locally but once deployed it does not work. I have tried several methods:

```
  Dim fName As String = "Test.docx"

    Dim t = Server.MapPath("~/Document_Files/Test.docx")

    Dim a = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Document_Files/Test.docx")

    Dim b = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Document_Files/Test.docx")

   Dim c = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Document_Files/Test.docx")

    Dim subfoldername = "Document_Files"

    Dim k = Server.MapPath("~/Document_Files/Test.docx")

    Dim f = "..\Document_Files\Test.docx"
 Dim testingDomain = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, subfoldername, fName)


 Dim applicationWord As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()

    applicationWord.Visible = True


    Dim doc As Document = applicationWord.Documents.Open(t, True)
```

the file is located :

```
C:\VBProjects\StudentSystem\StudentProject\Document_Files\Test.docx
```

all your help to get this working will be appreciated,

Comment: Is this "C:\VBProjects\StudentSystem\StudentProject\" the root folder of your project?

Comment: yes, it's the root folder of my project

Comment: What do you mean with " I am basically trying to open this file on server" ?? In your code you are showing only the path not other operations you are trying to do to that file

Comment: I have published my project on the server and it's not working there.. it's returning null value so it's unable to locate the file.. any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure HttpContext isnot null? Seems you are doing something cross-thread. Needs more infos I think

Comment: all the different variations ive listed are returnning null .. could you explain the cross-thread and how to resolve it please?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` will always return the path *as if the file exists*, even if the file does not exist. Do you happen to have that code inside a `Try...Catch` that ignores any exceptions?

Comment: No it's not inside try and catch.. shall i put it there and see ?

Comment: please check that drive have permission for the users.

Comment: A cross thread scenario might be: You are calling from Ajax to Server. In this case HttpContext is not the same of your page.

Comment: @Jane Please [edit] your question to show us the code which opens the file.

Comment: i've checked the permissions and all seems OK!

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've edited my code

Comment: @Jane That will open the document on the server, do you intend for it to be opened on the client machine?

Comment: @Andrew yes, please. what shall i do ?

Comment: @Jane Please see [Opening Word Document on Client Side from Asp.net Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11335125/1115360).

Comment: this code is inside a button so i want users when they click the button it opens the document

Comment: @AndrewMorton i can't do download as i need to prepopulate parts of the document with info from the application. any help?

Comment: @Jane If you google for ".net word nuget" you will find several packages which can enable you to do that. I suggest checking the licence terms and then trying one with plenty of examples available.